# chkrootkit LKM detected

Tags: 20.04, chkrootkit

Today I scanned my machine with the chkrootkit tool by running the command:

`sudo chkrootkit` And here are some of the results:

```
Checking `lkm'... 
You have 5 processes hidden for the readdir command 
You have 5 processes hidden for the ps command 
chkproc: Warning: There may be an LKM trojan installed 
chkdirs: nothing detected
```

After a while, these processes suddenly disappeared.

Is there any cause for concern? And if so, how can I fix the situation?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.6 and chkrootkit versions 0.53.

Maldet report:

```
Jan 04 2024 23:08:36 ssncorp maldet(420049): {scan} scan completed on /: files 35208, malware hits 0, cleaned hits 0, time 3143s.
```